# Need to get the insert_id value and pass it to another PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have this form function in **main.php** file to save submitted data in the database using Contact Form 7 plugin. I need to get the `$lastid` value from this function below and pass it to **query.php** to update my query based on ID. How to do that?

**main.php**

```
function user_data_form( $wpcf7 ) {

global $wpdb;

$title = $wpcf7->title();
$form = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ($form) {
        $data = $form->get_posted_data();

        if ( $title == 'User Data' ) {

            $name = $data['name'];
            $email = $data['email'];
            $bio = $data['bio'];
            $url = $data['url'];            

            $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'user_data', 
            array( 
                'name'  => $name,
                'email' => $email,
                'bio' => $bio,
                'url' => $url
                ), array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' )
            );
            $lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'user_data_form' );


define('ROOTDIR', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
    require_once(ROOTDIR . 'query.php');
```

**query.php**

```
$wpdb->update( $wpdb->prefix . 'user_data', 
    array( 'status' => $status ), 
    array( 'ID' => $lastid ), 
    array( '%s' ), array( '%d' ) 
);
```

I tried to use `array( 'ID' => $lastid )`, but it kept returning to null.

Comment: You can make it global variable so you can access it on query.php (like we do with `$wpdb` for example)

Comment: @Temani Thanks for the response, dear. So your suggestion would be: `global $lastid; $lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;` and in the **query.php**: `global $lastid; array( 'ID' => $lastid )` right?

Comment: yes and you need to declare the varialbe outside the function too. In main.php you may add outisde the funcion `$lastid=0;` and no need global in this file as the variable is visible. In the query.php it's like you did `global $lastid; array( 'ID' => $lastid )`

Comment: @Temani I'm sorry, but it's not working. I put the `$lastid = 0;` before the line `function user_data_form( $wpcf7 ) { ` just like you said, but it still returning to null value :(

Comment: by the way how you are calling the query in the query.php and when?

Comment: @Temani I call the query when some conditions are meet `if ($completed == 1) {` So far it's working except that the ID value won't show up and keep returning to null.